# How to make extra bump

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-painting

I have the reference image and im really confuse do i have to model it with the texture i can manage it. So i decided to have a texture if im going in correct path. I have a texture and i have unwrap but can i get extra bump with the nodes like the reference or do i have to model with the mesh. Any suggestion or help or any addon will work. Thanks

**Reference image**

[image]

**Image im wrapping it**

[image]

**Displacement modifier but result not smooth**

[image]

Comment: have you tried the Displace modifier?

Comment: @moonboots yes but did not get result as seen above

Comment: @moonboots i edit the question and displacement modifier but edge look wired not smooth

Comment: you need to put your Subsurf modifier below the Displace

Comment: maybe instead of Displace you should try something like the cactus by CG Cookie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZLmHnaj_A8

Comment: Quality of texture is the problem here. When using the image, it will give you artifacts because it doesn't have enough bit depth. Test with a higher resolution scanned texture that is greater than 8 bit depth.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a Minecraft skin that looks like a texture with Complementary shaders in Minecraft. I need to make bump lines wider but distance value does nothing. I'm using Eevee renderer.

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: This seems to be a question rather than an answer. Please ask this as a seperate question. You have posted this as an answer. There is a Ask Question Button in th etop right corner right after you open the homepage of the Blender Stack Exchange Site.